# Summation in R n times

Tags: r

I'm new to this site and to R and I'm going crazy to find the answer to these two summaries. Would you know what I did wrong in the code? The code is to be made to work with only one varinate, by typing summer(77). Thank you very much

```
i = 1
summer <- function(N){
  for (k in 1:N ) {
    sum((i-1)/i) 
    
  }
}

summer(77)
```

[Exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nafUZ.png)

Comment: in your code, the answer will always be zero. since i does not change

Comment: you should have `summer <- function(N){k <- 0;for (i in 1:N)  k = k + (i-1)/i; k}` or simply put `summer <- function(N) {i <- 1:N; sum(1-1/i)}`

Answer (score 0):

You should use R's built-in vectorization to help you here:

```r
summer <- function(N) sum(1 - seq(N)^-1)

summer(77)
#> [1] 72.0725
```

Answer (score 0):

With minimum modification to make your code work.

```
summer <- function(N) {
  total <- 0L
  for (i in 1:N ) {
    total <- total + (i - 1) / i 
  }
  total
}

summer(77)
# [1] 72.0725
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exploit R vector to do summations like these in this case 1:N creates the vector then you just need to do you calculations on said vector

```
what_we_do_on_each_step <- function(number) {
  1-1/number
}

what_we_do_on_each_step(1:10)

summer <- function(N) {
  
  vector <- 1:N
  vector_after_calculation <- what_we_do_on_each_step(vector)
  sum(vector_after_calculation)
  }

summer(10)
```

Or simply

```
summer_simple <- function(N) {
  sum(1-1/1:N)
} 

summer_simple(10)
```